# AJAX call inside Ckeditor widget's upcast function

Tags: ajax, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I would like to use an AJAX call (via jQuery) to change the HTML of a widget during the upcast function of a CKEditor widget. Here is what I have tried:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('mywidget', {
  requires: 'widget',
  icons: 'mywidget',
  init: function (editor) {
    editor.widgets.add('mywidget', {
      button: 'My widget',
      template: '<p class="mywidget">Initial text.</p>',
      allowedContent: 'p(!mywidget)',
      upcast: function (element) {
        if (element.hasClass('mywidget')) {
          element.setHtml('After upcasting.');
          $.get('http://example.com')
            .done(function (response) {
              element.setHtml('Updated text after AJAX.');
            });
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    });
  }
});
```

When the widget is first instantiated, as expected, it says:

"Initial text."

After I click "Source" and then click "Source" again, as expected again, the text has changed to:

"After upcasting"

However, when the AJAX request comes back, the text does not change to "Updated text after AJAX".

Does anyone know how I can get at the element from inside the AJAX callback? If it is too late to access the element from the AJAX callback, is there any way to use the response from the callback to retroactively edit the markup of the already-upcasted widget? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` is asynchronous so the `.done` part is called after the upcasting had already completed. Use `$.ajax()` instead and set `async: false`.

The modified widget code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('mywidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'mywidget',
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('mywidget', {
            button: 'My widget',
            template: '<p class="mywidget">Initial text.</p>',
            allowedContent: 'p(!mywidget)',
            upcast: function (element) {
                if (element.hasClass('mywidget')) {
                    element.setHtml('After upcasting.');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://www.example.com',
                        async: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            element.setHtml('Updated text after AJAX.');
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. That does work. I'd like to still hold out for a possible asynchronous approach, since "async:false" seems to be discouraged. I edited the question to clarify that I'm wondering if there is any way to retroactively change the markup of the already-upcasted widget, since as you point out, it is too late to affect the element in the upcast function.

Comment: Since I never figured out another answer, accepting this one, thanks!